# Have trouble creating ElasticSearch Domain through AWS CLI due to InvalidTypeException

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, command-line-interface

I am following tutorial for using Kibana with AWS elastic Search as per:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-walkthrough.html

Specifically, tutorial ask me to execute this line (after repacing user info) in order to create a new ElasticSearch Domain:

> > aws es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name my-transcribe-test --elasticsearch-version 6.2 --elasticsearch-cluster-config  InstanceType=t2.medium.elasticsearch,InstanceCount=1 --ebs-options EBSEnabled=true,VolumeType=standard,VolumeSize=10 --access-policies '{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"},"Action":"es:*","Resource":"arn:aws:es:us-west-2:123456789012:domain/my-transcribe-test/*"}]}' --region us-west-2

I replaced it with my own info:

> > aws es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name my-transcribe-test2 --elasticsearch-version 6.2 --elasticsearch-cluster-config  InstanceType=t2.medium.elasticsearch,InstanceCount=1 --ebs-options EBSEnabled=true,VolumeType=standard,VolumeSize=10 --access-policies '{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::31865135xxxx:user:xxxx"},"Action":"es:*","Resource":"arn:aws:es:us-east-1:31865135xxxx:domain/my-transcribe-test2"}]}' --region us-east-1

However, I get error:

> > An error occurred (InvalidTypeException) when calling the CreateElasticsearchDomain operation: Error setting policy: [{Version:2012-10-17,Statement:[{Effect:Allow,Principal:{AWS:arn:aws:iam::318651355992:user/xxxx},Action:es:*,Resource:arn:aws:es:us-east-1:31865135xxxx:domain/my-transcribe-test2}]}]

At first I thought it was because I made an error in access policy, however, I created the exact same domain/policy using AWS console without error:

> > {
> >       "Version": "2012-10-17",
> >       "Statement": [
> >         {
> >           "Effect": "Allow",
> >           "Principal": {
> >             "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::31865135xxxx:user/xxxx"
> >           },
> >           "Action": "es:*",
> >           "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:318651355992:domain/my-transcribe-test2"
> >         }
> >       ]
> >     }

So it can't be that the policy I created is structured wrong.  I have to be doing something wrong in the CLI when creating this domain/policy. Is anyone able to help me to identify the mistake? Thank you.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? ran into the exact same issue

Comment: I recommend you use this tool to build aws CLI commands https://awsclibuilder.com/